# Is there a way to query a website for a url with incorrect case?

Tags: http, curl, http-headers, wget, httpie

I have this zsh function that finds the readme of github projects from their root link (e.g., https://github.com/Mortennn/Dozer -> https://github.com/Mortennn/Dozer/blob/master/README.md). Because the casing of this file is inconsistent (e.g., `readme Readme READMe`), I am currently trying all possible case permutations, which is very slow.

Is there a more efficient solution?

```
#There are lots of stuff here, just ignore them. You can ignore this code completely, too. The question is self-sufficient.
for readme in "${(0@)$(permute-case readme)}"
do
i2="${i}/blob/master/${readme}.md"
silence wget --spider "$i2" && break
i2="${i}/blob/master/${readme}.rst"
silence wget --spider "$i2" && break
done
```

Comment: Why don't you get the file listing, parse it yourself and then request the correct file?

Comment: @paddy Is that a general solution, or does it work just with github? If you mean that I just scrape the github's page for the link, I'll rather go with this slow method. The reason I asked this question is more to see if there is a way to query http servers, not to parse the frontends.

Comment: The question appears to be specific to GitHub.  Are you looking for a general solution?  It is entirely up to the webserver to determine whether to treat a URI as case-sensitive.  If you just want something for GitHub, and want an efficient solution, then I don't understand why you prefer the non-efficient method that may potentially get you blocked due to systematically probing non-existent URLs.

Comment: Note also that on the first link you provided (the project main page), the HTTP-ified contents of the readme are inside a `<div>` with the id `readme`.

Comment: @paddy I actually want the raw markdown to feed into pandoc, but as I said, I am really interested in a way to query http servers for case insensitive urls.